# A way to make python print centered text in .txt?

Tags: python, spaces

Is there any way to make Python write into a .txt file and make the text appear in center?

Also is there any way to make a long space in a text line?
Like, it would look like this `Hello______________________Stacy`, of course there would be space instead of _.

Any way to do so?

Comment: Lots of ways ... But we'd need to know how many spaces there should be (or the logic to determine how many spaces there should be).  e.g. the text is appearing in the center of what?

Comment: While @Wajdi Farhani's answer is great, I don't think it solves your problem.

Centering all depends on how the person views the text. If I view it in a terminal, it will truncate after 80 characters generally, but if I were to view it in an IDE, it could be much wider. 

That is why there are markup languages, so that text is displayed irrelevant of size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
# You can change 20 by whatever you want

str = "centered"
print str.center(20, ' ')

>>                  centered

#Than to make spaces: 

print "it"+(" "*20)+"works" 

>> it                  works
```